# SimpMessagingTemplate not sending messages

Tags: spring-boot, sockets, websocket, java-websocket

Here is my simple React component:

```
`import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

```
function App() {const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
```

```
useEffect(() => {const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5001/socket");
```

```
socket.onopen = () => {
  console.log("WebSocket connected");

  // Subscribe to the topic when the connection is established
  socket.send(JSON.stringify({
    type: "subscribe",
    destination: "/topic/dummy"
  }));
  console.log("Subscribed to topic /topic/dummy");
};

socket.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log("Got event!");
  
};

socket.onclose = (event) => {
  console.log("WebSocket closed with code: " + event.code);
};

return () => {
  socket.close();
};
```

```
}, []);
```

```
return (<div>Hello</div>);}
```

```
export default App;`
```

Here are my web configuration classes in spring-boot app:

```
`@Configuration@EnableWebSocketMessageBrokerpublic class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
```

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/socket").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
    registry.addEndpoint("/socket").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();

}
```

```
}`
```

Here is my class that sends a message:

```
@Service@Slf4jpublic class DummyService {
```

```
@Autowiredprivate SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
```

```
public void dummyCall() {messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/dummy", "MESSAGE");System.out.println("Message sent!");}}
```

So the problem is:
I start spring-boot app, and the React app after it, and I get logs in the browser:
WebSocket connected
Subscribed to topic /topic/dummy

After I call a rest method from postman which triggers dummyCall() function, I get the "Message sent!" log in spring-boot console, but nothing in my browser, like it didn't get the message. I am really confused about how to debug this, as logs in spring-boot app suggest that WS connection is established.

I tried a log of different configurational stuff and switched to dummy example and really don't know how to get to the end of this.